# TextView.setView() does not update text

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

From a fragment I start an activty, that opens a new fragment. Also I pass a string value from the first fragment (`AllDishes`) over the activity to the last fragment (`DishDetailView`) via intent. 
The fragment (`DishDetailView`) is set as context to a layout (`fragment_dishdetailview`), but when I try to set the text that was passed, the view is not getting updated.

When I debug my app, the string parameter (`"Test"`) seems to be passed and also the text of the `TextView` `name` seems to be set correctly, as you can see in the screenshot below, but somehow the UI (`fragment_dishdetailview`) is not getting updated, it´s just empty.

I´m not sure whether the update of the UI or the way of passing the value from one fragment to another is the problem. My aim is to open the fragment (`DishDetailView`) from fragment (`AllDishes`) and pass a string from the first to the second fragment. So actually I don´t need the activity but without I was not able to pass the String.

[image]

**AllDishes (fragment)**

```
@Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Dish dish = ca.getItem(position);

                Intent intent = new Intent(rootView.getContext(), DishDetailsViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("nameToPass" , dish.name);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

**DishDetailView (fragment)**

```
public class DishDetailView extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dishdetailview, container, false);

        String tempHolder = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("nameToPass");

        TextView name = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textview_view_dishName);

        name.setText(tempHolder);

        rootView.invalidate();

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dishdetailview, container, false);
    }
}
```

**DishDetailsViewActivity (activity)**

```
public class DishDetailsViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dish_details_view);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**fragment_dishdetailview.xml (fragment layout)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/screen_background"
    tools:context=".fragments.DishDetailView">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_view_dishName"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/headercolor"
        android:textSize="@dimen/header_fontsize"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

** content_dish_details_view.xml (activity layout)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph3" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**nav-graph.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph3"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragment_dishdetailview">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_dishdetailview"
        android:name="com.example.nutritracker.fragments.DishDetailView"
        android:label="DishDetailView"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dishdetailview">
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should return your `rootView` on the `onCreateView` method of `DishDetailView`.

Comment: Oh I didn´t expect that it was that easy but it worked. Thanks!